# Categories not showing products listed

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

On the magento back end under catalog>manage categories it will not show me the items in the categories. However when I go to catalog>manage products it does show me the products.

I have flushed and refreshed the cache as well as re indexing everything.

Comment: can you please go to Catalog > Manage Categories and hit "Reset Filter". It might be some filter already applied. Please check again.

Comment: i can not find the button that says reset filter.

Comment: it won't even let create a new category